# How do I set window length and shift length for computing STFT on Scipy?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, frequency-spectrum, stft, scipy

Does `nperseg=32, noverlap=16` mean the window length is 32mS with a shift of 16mS?

[Refer here for more details](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html)

Comment: it's in samples, not seconds

Comment: Btw, librosa has a very nice STFT implementation. And documentation has lots more examples than scipy https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.stft.html

Answer (score -1):

for this function:

- nperseg will set the number of samples to output from your STFT.
- noverlap will specify how many old samples you want to take to calculate your future STFT.

Let's say you want a stft of size 256 with an overlap of 50% you will set noverlap = 128.
128 samples will then be taken from the old segment that was used to calculate the previous STFT...

For more information about STFT and the interest of overlap I invite you to watch this discussion.

[STFT: why overlapping the window?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/19311/stft-why-overlapping-the-window)